# How can I resolve installation error with Laravel LaraAdmin?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to setup a fresh install of LaraAdmin
http://laraadmin.com

I've been following these instructions:
http://laraadmin.com/docs/1.0/installation#install

I receive an error when I get to the step of running

```
php artisan la:install
```

The Error received is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider' not found
```

I tried installing 3 times, twice with a local composer installation and once with a global composer installation - both resulting in the same error.

I've also confirmed that `Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider::class` is included in the providers section of config/app.php

When I change `Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider::class` to `Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProviderASDF::class` in config/app.php - the error becomes:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProviderASDF' not found
```

So it's clear that the added line of code in config/app.php triggers this error.

How can I resolve the class not found error?

Comment: try to restart your server and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @AmrAly, I've restarted the server and ran `composer dump-autoload` and I still get the same class not found error when running `php artisan la:install`

Comment: you have laravel 5.2 installed?

Comment: @AmrAly I ran `composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2.31 la1` from the instructions on http://laraadmin.com/docs/1.0/installation#install to install laravel 5.2.31

Comment: have you changed the permissions for these directories `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/ database/migrations/`

Comment: @AmrAly, yes. I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/ database/migrations/` inside of the `la1` directory prior to running php artisan la:install - still receive the same error after doing that.

I believe the class that needs to be loaded is located in `webroot/vendor/dwij/laraadmin/src/LAProvider.php`

While my laravel installation is located in `webroot/la1`

Could that directory structure perhaps be related to the cause of this error?

Comment: No, I have followed the steps and it works fine.i would say to delete the current project and try to redo the installation process .

Comment: @AmrAly, I've done that several times and still get the error. Would you mind sharing what your development environment is? For exmple: ubuntu server 16.04, apache2, php 7.0 (that's what I'm using)

Comment: Trying to register the class with `php artisan tinker` then `App::register('\Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider');` Produces the error: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class '\Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider' not found`

Comment: Did you try `php artisan config:cache` after adding the Service Provider?

Comment: @RuChernChong running any php artisan command after adding the Service Provider produces that error, I can't even run php artisan tinker without commenting out the Service Provider

Comment: @NickShaw that might be a problem with your file structure. Here is what my repo looks like [here](https://github.com/AmroAly/laravel-laraadmin) just clone it then cd inside the project , copy .env.example to .env , then php artisan key:generate and and run `composer install` then `php artisan la:install`

Comment: @AmrAly I've cloned your repo, coppied .env.example to .env and get an error when running php artisan key:generate inside of the laravel-laraadmin directory. Posting Error in next comment (not enough chars left)

Comment: @AmrAly Here's the error: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/webroot/laraadmin/laravel-laraadmin/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/webroot/laraadmin/laravel-laraadmin/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/webroot/laraadmin/laravel-laraadmin/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/webroot/laraadmin/laravel-laraadmin/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Comment: @AmrAly I ran the tree command and compared the results of your repo vs my default Laravel/LaraAdmin install.  The only differences I've found in terms of file structure are that I have this file and yours doesn't: bootstrap/cache/services.php and I have a vendor directory which you likely have ignored with git.

Comment: @AmrAly I resolved the php error from my previous comments by pasting my vendors directory into your repo. Oddly enough, I still get the same error as with a fresh install when using php artisan (with any artisan command): [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider' not found

Comment: of-course since the vendor directory is generated by the composer install command. it is probably you havent installed the laraadmin package correctly

Comment: @AmrAly I cloned your repo into a new directory, am I missing a step before that?

Comment: no. so my repo doesnt work on your machine??

Comment: @AmrAly I just got it to work, I had to install laraadmin to the webroot directory, installing it in any sub directory of webroot causes this error. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import laraAdmin classes first via composer in the terminal:

```
composer require "dwij/laraadmin:1.0.40"
```

After that, you'll be fine running `php artisan la:install`

Answer (score 1):

Paste this line bottom of the providers in config/app.php
Dwij\Laraadmin\LAProvider::class